# A hardware interrupt vs. an aperiodic task

Tags: task, interrupt, scheduling, rtos

What is the relationship between the two terms? Is it that an [ISR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) will be executed immediately, but an aperiodic task can be scheduled later (using the principle of a polling server or deferred server)?

Comment: Without more context I would say there isn't much of a relationship between HW-Interrupt and Aperiodic Task.  "Aperiodic" simply means not periodic.  Both HW interrupts and tasks can be either periodic or aperiodic.  It depends on the application.  Are you asking what is the difference between an interrupt and a task?

Comment: @kkrambo, so if to speak strictly about HW-Interrupts, say buttons on a keyboard being pressed, is it usually that the ISR creates or triggers an aperiodic task, which itself "deciphers" the user's input in context of a particular system?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it, but it's not the only way.  It's not my usual way but it might be someone else's.  With user buttons, you have to design a debounce mechanism and human perception of a button push response is much slower than an interrupt response.  Therefore polling the button status from a periodic task can be a very adequate design.  Also I want to point out that in your example, the task is aperiodic because the ISR trigger is aperiodic because the button push is aperiodic.  Aperiodicity can be due to the nature of the inputs rather than a purposeful design decision.

Comment: The terms are not related. The question makes little sense without more context.  "aperiodic" simply means _"not periodic"_.  Are you rather asking about the difference between handling an asynchronous event in an interrupt handler or within a task context?  Even then the event is likely to cause an interrupt that is either handled directly or deferred to a task context.  You then add the terms _"Polling and Deferred Server"_ - you are just expanding your gamut of scheduling patterns.  I think you need to ask a different question; perhaps describe with concrete examples what you are comparing.

Comment: Don't get fixated on "aperiodoc task" like it is something very specific.  It is just a task.  Some tasks are periodic, some are triggered on asynchronous events - that is just a task.